# how to open popup/menu item within listview item in Xamarin forms?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin forms.
I want to open a popup/menu list on clicking the listview item at right most position of the clicked item. Something like here in the screen shot. Here on clicking the three dot image I want to open the menu list.[image]

Answer (score 0):

> open a popup/menu list ?

I suggest that you can use some third-part package from nuget.For example [Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfPopupLayout](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfPopupLayout/) .

It provides a layout that allows users to display an alert message with customizable buttons or load any desired view inside a pop-up. It provides options to fully customize the pop-up with custom header, body, and footer capabilities, allowing you to display important information to use precisely how user want to.

[image]

For more detail you can refer the [document](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfpopuplayout/getting-started)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't want to use third-part package.

Comment: I looked into this and either the screenshot is misleading or the documentation is lacking. I couldn't find a way to achieve this. In ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) , the sender is the ListView itself and the e.SelectedItem is the View Model object. So I can't access the View to be parameter for .ShowRelativeToView